# How do you provide subscripts and superscripts in your comments?

Tags: formatting, text

I want to write a comment (text) describing what's happening in my function.  I want the text to appear like this:

**Note that the ElectronNumberDensity is in units of $cm^{-3}$. Thompson cross section is in units of $cm^2$.**

(With no line break). However, as soon as I type the superscript (using ctrl-^), Mathematica inserts a hard line break like there's a new style or something.

**Note that the ElectronNumberDensity is in units of**

**$cm^{-3}$. Thompson cross section is in units of $cm^2$.**

What is the proper way to type in comments or helpful text that makes use of typesetting?

Comment: Enter in InputForm, e.g., TraditionalForm@Superscript[cm, -3] then highlight and evaluate in place.

Comment: That appears to be the answer.  Please post it as an answer and I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enter in InputForm, e.g., TraditionalForm@Superscript[cm, -3] then highlight and [`Evaluate in Place`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/EvaluateInPlace.html).

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> to start an inline cell (see [this page for keyboard shortcuts](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/KeyboardShortcutListing)).  Oddly, while the shortcut for ending an inline cell is <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>)</kbd>, I need to use CTRL - 0 (i.e. no shift).